# Finding out what the page is loading in with PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a directory and on some MOD_REWRITES. I have actually deleted the .htaccess file form the site, But there is still something overwriting it.

Is there any PHP Variables that I can use to find out where the over hanging .htaccess file is being loaded from?

There are so many files, that I fear that there may even be more than one.

Cheers guys

Comment: Whats the directory and what's your root htaccess

Comment: Check in your apache settings for this <directory> if anything else overwrites something.

Comment: @RobertPitt the Dir is the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess files are processed in the order they're found, so if there's one overriding things for your page, it would be in one or more of the parent directories. There's also the main server httpd.conf files, which are a preferred location for long-standing .htaccess directives, as that's read only once at server startup, and not per-request as .htaccess files are.

Comment: Thanks Marc B. There are roughly 6 sub directories and they have mod_rewrite.php within them. Looks like I'm going to need to check them all out :/

Answer (score 3):

Confusing title.

To answer your title question: do print_r($REQUEST) and find a variable you like.

To answer your body question: check each parent directory's .htaccess, until you hit the root.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `/etc/apache2/...` configuration files, but first make sure you deleted and `.htaccess` is not just hidden (in unix, files starting with `.` are hidden by default).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look for hidden files.